# Query only title/field/featured media of posts

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, query-posts, rest-api

I'm going to develop a Wordpress plugin as a webesrvice for mobile application.
How can I get only title/id/featured media of posts in wordpress plugins?
I had a look at [wordpress developer documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/), it will return list of posts and can filter them however it returns all information for post, but to be efficient I only need 3 fields {id,title,featured media}.

How can I query this information in wordpress, bt not the whole post information?

Comment: Maybe you should read about the [REST API](http://wp-api.org/), that give you the relevant information as JSON string, much better for a webservice outside the WP instance. if you will reduce the information of the request can you enhance the instance with the plugin [wp-rest-api-filter-items](https://github.com/bueltge/wp-rest-api-filter-items)

Comment: I was using it but I did't not know how to do that, this was a real nice help!

Comment: @bueltge can you please take a look at [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/241271/86163), too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make query like this

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',  //Specyfying post type
    'cat'=> 1,    //Selecting post category by ID to show
    'posts_per_page' => 10,  //No. of posts to show     
    'paged' => $paged       //For pagination
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    //To show Title of post
    the_title();     
    //To show ID of post
    $id = get_the_ID();
    echo $id;   
    /*****     Featured Media     ******/
the_post_thumbnail(
array(120, 90),   //Width and height of featured image
    array(

    'class' => 'thumbnail',   //class to apply css properties
    'alt' => 'post thumbnail', //Alternate text if there is no image to show
    'title' => 'my custom title' //Title to specify
)
);
/*******     Featured Media Ends   ********/
endwhile;
```