# Get featured image and additional posts thumbnail Wordpress REST API

Tags: post-thumbnails, rest-api

I want to use the REST API of wordpress to build a new version of a custom theme. I'm able to get the json response of a particular category, but I need to find a way to obtain also the featured image or the second post thumbnail registered using a plugin, so I can use them in the layout. Is this possible without using a plugin?

here is the code I'm using for testing:

```
<script>
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?category_name=portfolio&per_page=50&_embed', function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $.each(response, function(i){
        console.log(response[i]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url);
      });
    });

  });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

the last part of the console log will not work but the `[0].source_url` is the info I need for each JSON post provided.

Comment: You'll need to add that field in to the REST API response, but keep in mind that you should probably raise this as a feature request for that plugin via their support mechanism. If there was a plugin that would do this, it would be the plugin you're using, or from the same vendor. I think the best you can hope for is how to add fields to the response the REST API gives, or add a piece of post meta to it, otherwise the specifics of this specific plugin you're using require speciailist knowledge of that plugin which would be offtopic on this site

Comment: I'm not using a plugin, I wrote my own if needed or use the native CMS functions. I want only to use the `source_url` to obtain the url from the response, it will give me an undefined error for now i chrome console.

Comment: hmm if the `source_url` doesn't work, how did you come upon it to begin with? Note that the `the second post thumbnail registered using a plugin,` part can't be answered at the moment as there's zero information about the plugin you wrote and how it stores information

Comment: ´source_url´ is a parameter that will be returned from the API key when the `_embed` querystring param is used. For the second plugin is the famous Multiple post thumbnail, but I don't have a link to it

Comment: Did you add the `category_name` field by custom code? Because it's not a standard argument - you should use [`categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments). But if `console.log( response[i] )` doesn't include the `source_url`, then it's probably because the post indeed doesn't have a featured image. If it does have one, but set via the plugin, then you should ask/search on the plugin support forums/site.

Comment: No, I don't use custom code, I've only passed the same param of the wp query and it's work

Comment: "same param of the wp query" - not all of that params are supported by the REST API. And in my tests, when I used `category_name`, I did get some posts, but from all categories. Then I tried `?categories=123` (`123` is the category ID) and it worked well.

Comment: If I use `categories` it will not load in my case, maybe because on my dev envoirment I don't use the last wordpress version? I need to get the portfolio category and I don't know the id, this is why I'm using the category_name param.

Comment: Well, if you don't know the ID, there's no point using the `categories` param - i.e. `categories=<Name>` won't work. But why don't you know the ID? You could just find it from the admin page? Unless if you don't have admin access to the REST API site. Btw, I'm using WP 5.2, haven't yet updated to 5.3.

Comment: This is the forst time I'm using the REST API of wp, normally I will query the db using the WP_Query way so I can use the `category_name` param, this is why I don't care about the ID of the categories. I will try using the ID.

Comment: Alright, let us know how it goes. And I already linked you to the docs, so be sure to read it..

Comment: solved!thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WP Rest API: details of latest post including featured media url in one request?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241271/wp-rest-api-details-of-latest-post-including-featured-media-url-in-one-request)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var items = [];
    $.getJSON('https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?category_name=portfolio&per_page=50&_embed', function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $.each(response, function(key,val){
        //console.log(val._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url);
        items.push(''+''+
                     '');
      });
    });

  });
}(jQuery));

//use variable array to push data
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you explained what this code does so that @sialfa can understand what to do to it if it ever needs to be modified in the future.